# Degree of polynomials $\mathbb Q\sqrt[3]{2}:\mathbb Q$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I want to show [$\mathbb Q\sqrt[3]{2}:\mathbb Q]=3$. I would assume that I would set it up as:[$\mathbb Q\sqrt[3]{2}:\mathbb Q\sqrt{2}][\mathbb Q\sqrt{2}:\mathbb Q]$. I know that [$\mathbb Q\sqrt{2}:\mathbb Q]=2$ and I thought [$\mathbb Q\sqrt[3]{2}:\mathbb Q\sqrt{2}]=3$? So I get 6. Am I approaching this incorrectly?

Answer (score 6):

$\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]2)$ is not an extension of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt2)$, because $\sqrt2$ is not in the former field.

The "correct" way to prove that $[\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]2):\Bbb Q]=3$ is to note that $\{1,\sqrt[3]2,\sqrt[3]4\}$ forms a basis.

Comment: oh wow I can't believe I overlooked that. I must be working too quickly. Just a clarification question: can you always use the "size" of a basis to determine degree?

Comment: @KMath By definition, the degree of the extension $L:K$ is the dimension of $L$ as a vector space over $K$, which is by definition the size of the basis of the vector space concerned.

Comment: You really need to work on definitions.

Comment: Thanks for your input!